# How to solve $f(x)+f^{-1}(x)=f'(x)+\ln x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, inverse-function

When I was playing around with functional equations, I came up with a problem which has a simple trivial answer.

I'm talking about the following equation:

$f(x)+f^{-1}(x)=f'(x)+\ln x$

The trivial solution is $f(x)=e^x$, but it's not clear to me how would one go about solving for $f(x)$ from scratch.

Is it even possible to solve such an equation without guessing? Are there any methods that can be used to tackle functional differential equations involving the inverse function?

Comment: In this particular case, rearrange the equation to $\,f(x)-f'(x) = \ln x-f^{-1}(x)\,$ and set them both to $0$.

Comment: Why are we justified in setting it equal to 0, besides knowing in advance that that will produce two equations giving the same function as a result?